# Google Maps API: setCenter from markers possible?

Tags: google-maps

I have set of markers on Google map.
Is it possible to center the map in the way that all markers will be visible, and zoom level will also be auto adjusted?

Exactly the same way how Goolge Static Maps API does when you specify markers and do not specify center/zoom parameters (Implicit Positioning of the Map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `var myBounds = google.maps.LatLngBounds()` and basically extend all the points you have.  Once you have all the points in the LatLngBounds() you can use your `map.fitBounds(myBounds);` and all marker should be visible and centered.

do you wish me to prototype a jsfiddle?

Comment: i didn't quite understand the question can you please elaborate?

Comment: No question. All is ok. I just said that I had to add the "new" keyword before constructor to make it work. That's it.